# Ordering Users in a Django ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, sorting, manytomanyfield

I have a model that has a ManyToManyField of Users:

**models.py**

```
class Excuse(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**views.py**

```
def excuse_list(request, block_id=None):
    queryset = Excuse.objects.all().prefetch_related('students')
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "excuses/excuse_list.html", context)
```

**Template** (excuse_list.html)

```
...
{% for excuse in object_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ excuse.reason }}</td>
      <td>
        {% for student in excuse.students.all %}
          {{student.get_full_name}};
        {% endfor %}
      </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

How can I sort the User set (`excuse.students.all`) alphabetically by a User field, for example: user.last_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this just changing your `views.py` with this:

```
queryset = Excuse.objects.all().prefetch_related(
Prefetch('students', queryset=User.objects.order_by('lastname')))
```

> remember to import User model!

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is the best of the three answers so far because it is contained within prefetch, so there won't be a pile of additional hits on the database?  Note that the User field should be `last_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your Excuse model, that will return a sorted students set:

```
def get_sorted_students(self):
    return self.students.all().order_by('last_name')
```

And then in your template use `excuse.get_sorted_students` instead of `excuse.students.all`

Alternatively, you could use a custom template tag to render the list of students.